# Excel VBA Copying Sheets to a New Workbook and emailing the New Workbook in Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a segment of code that attaches the current file to an e-mail addressed to our sales rep y is equal to the sales rep email. and to the orders email for our company.

Instead of attaching the whole document to this email I want to copy tabs from the document and paste them into a new document. Then send only the new document (thereby reducing file size and hopefully changing it from a .xlsm attachment to a .xls attachment).

```
If ShapesAfter > ShapesBefore Then
    MsgBox "Please Repair Invalid Equipment Selection", , "Invalid Selections _
 Have Been Made"

ElseIf ShapesAfter = ShapesBefore Then
   Sheets("inputs").Select
   Dim y As String
   y = Cells(61, 5).Value
   Sheets("config").Select
  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show "" & y & "; " & "orders@domainname.com"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above example is returning Run-time '9' error. Here is corrected code:

```
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Set wb = Workbooks.Add
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("inputs").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("config").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
   wb.Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show "" & y & "; " & "orders@domainname.com"


   Set wb = Nothing
```

"ThisWorkbook." has to be added there.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new workbook object and copy the sheets to it.  Example below.

```
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Set wb = Workbooks.Add
   Sheets("inputs").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
   Sheets("config").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
   wb.Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show "" & y & "; " & "orders@domainname.com"


  Set wb = Nothing
```

Comment: How do i switch back from the new workbook to the one which was already opened?

Comment: Answer to ^: Workbooks("WhateverFile.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Comment: this solution threw an error. Matus Morongs answer below did the trick.